# Arrays? or not?

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, 2d, addressbook

i am not an expert in java, but i need to solve this problem/activity for my course subject, that's why i really need your help guys. I have a programming problem. thing is i can't figure out what method or java codes should i use for this problem:

**Create a class address book that can contain 100 entries of Name, Address, contact number and email address.
You should provide the following methods for the address book:**

**Add entry, Delete entry, View all entries and Update an entry**

UPDATE: this is the codes I got so far

I am thinking i could use *2d array* for this but, as soon as i start coding *i can't really continue further*, I don't know if its possible to use array or not in this kind of activity. *I tried searching for other java codes* but the more I learned new techniques or codes that might be possible, the more i *got confused* on WHAT codes must I use!

**if anyone can help me *build the coding for this activity* I would really apprecaite and will surely study how the hell will/can YOU do it! because im really interested in learning Java, I just need some help to realize how should i DO this. thanks in advance!**

THIS ARE THE CODES I'VE GOT SO FAR:
the capability of these program is only for adding editing viewing and deleting NAMES, iam still figuring out how to add dimensions to my array or should I add? or if not array? HoW? how am I supposed to answer this activity prior tto its REQUIREMENTS :(

```
package javaactivities;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AddressBook {
        static  List<String> l=new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean y=true;  
 do{   
     System.out.println("Enter \n1 to add an entry\n2 to edit entry");
     System.out.println("3 to delete an entry\n4 to view entries\n5 to exit");
     System.out.print("enter your choice: ");
     int choice=in.nextInt();
     switch(choice)
     {
        case 1:
            insert();
            break;
        case 2:
            edit();
            break;
        case 3:
            delete();
            break;
        case 4:
            print();
            break;
        case 5:
            toexit();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("bad input");
            break;
    }
    System.out.println("want to process more? y/n");
    String x=in.next();
    char ch=x.charAt(0); 
    if( ch=='n')
        y=false;
}
while(y!=false);

}

static public void insert(){


   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    boolean y=true;
   do{
        System.out.println("enter name to add in list");
        String entry=in.next();
            l.add(entry);
        System.out.println("want to insert more?y/n");
        String x=in.next();
        char ch=x.charAt(0);
        if( ch=='n')
            y=false;
     }
   while(y!=false);
```

}

```
static public void print(){


   if(l.isEmpty())
       System.out.println("list is empty ");
   else
        System.out.println("members of lists are:");
        for(int i=0 ; i<l.size();i++)
            System.out.println("Entry "+i+" : "+ l.get(i)+" ");
```

}

```
static public void edit(){


   Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

   String num2;
   System.out.println("enter name you want to add");
   num2=in.next();
         try{
            System.out.println("enter entry # of the name you want to edit");
            int num1=in.nextInt();
            l.set(num1, num2);
         }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
                System.err.println("caught IndexOutOfBoundsException: specified position is empty "+e.getMessage());
           }

      }



static public void delete(){


    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter entry # you want to delete");
    int num=in.nextInt();
    l.remove(num);

}

static public void toexit(){

    System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Comment: *Entry* is a class (with `name`, `address` etc. fields), `AddressBook` is also a class which stores the `Entry`s in, say, `ArrayList<Entry>`

Comment: hi Dmitry, can you please help me, I am quit familiar about classes, methods, calling method, setting or getting methods. BUT I dont have any idea how should I store the objects(name,add etc.) and be able to delete, edit and view the entries that has been entered. Im thinking about using 2d arrays but i have no idea how should i use it.

Comment: It is 1d array of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, implement all the required classes, two in your case:

- AddressBook
- Entry

The skeleton could be something like that

```
public final class AddressBook {
  public static final class Entry {
    private String name; 
    private String address; 
    private String contactNumber;      
    private String email;  

    private Entry(String name, String address, String contactNumber, String email) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.contactNumber = contactNumber;
      this.email = email;
    }

    public String getName() {return name;}
    public String getAddress() {return address;}
    public String getContactNumer() {return contactNumber;}
    public String getEmail() {return email;}
  }

  private ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>();

  public AddressBook() {;}

  public int size() {return entries.size();}
  public int get(int index) {return entries.get(index);}
  ...
  public Entry add(String name, String address, String contactNumber, String email) {
    Entry entry = new Entry(name, address, contactNumber, email);

    entries.add(entry);

    return entry;
  }
  ...
}
```

In order to implement `viewAll()` you could choose to override `toString()` methods in both classes, to `delete()` it seemes that you have to implement `find()` as well etc. Then just use these classes

```
  public final class Main {
    private static AddressBook book = new AddressBook();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      ...
      switch(choice) {
        case 1: 
          book.add(...);
          break;
        case 2:
          book.delete(...);
          break;
        ...
      }

      System.out.println(book.toString());
      ...
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time sir Dmitry! :) I had my activity done although different from your codes. I appreciate it and will study this codes you've given! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As you have several entries to store my suggestion is a linked list. Linked list is a data structure where you can store multiple entries.Java provide a

http://www.mycstutorials.com/articles/data_structures/linkedlists
this link will help you with linked list.

Comment: I already ahd some codes I personally tried, but this codes only ask adn stores names, I still need to figure out how can I add address, number and email on my array. thanks.

Comment: If you think that it is difficult to work with linked list. have several arrays. An array for names , an array for telephone numbers... for a single person's entries have the same index in all arrays.

Comment: actually I can't uderstand using linked list. but im still trying to be familiar with what link you provided. anway thanks for taking the time to help,.